# Splash Screen is resizing when switching to Main Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

im currently working on an xamarin.forms application, which then will get shipped to android and ios.

In the end it is just an in app browser implementation of our website, so that cookie handling for our customers is secured.

Main Problem right now is that the splashscreen does a resize when switching to the main activity, at least that's what it looks like, this doesn't happen in the Android Emulator with android 9.0, but on my pixel 2 with android 10.

But see for yourself:

[image: Spash Screen Resizeing]

The Application has right now 2 Activities.

1.Splash Activity

```
[Activity(Theme ="@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity 
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*... shortend for readability ...*/
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));            
    }
}
```

2. Main Activity

```
[Activity(Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Base", MainLauncher = false)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    /* ... some more stuff... */
}
```

3. My Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Any Ideas why this happens and how to prevent that would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

*** Update  ***

splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="#fff"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/alwbg"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: can you also post the splash_screen layout `@drawable/splash_screen`

Comment: @LeoJebran here you go

Comment: Just a guess but does changing `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` to `false` fix the issue?

Comment: @patrick.elmquist no it does not

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem, then post that as an answer with an answer post below. You can do that even if it is your own question. In fact, [we explicit encourage self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Developer instrumentation is the cause for the flicker
When i disabled it, it won't appear anymore.

**How to disable the Developer Instrumentation:**
(VS 2019)

[image: Disabling Developer instrumentation stops the flickering]

Comment: Is this for eclipse or android studio? Where can I find these settings in android studio?

Comment: @MalachiHolden i use Visual Studio, so i don't know where those settings are buried there, but it seems you found a solution already. ;)

Comment: @Isparia I have the same issue, but this solution doesn't work for me. Are you sure you didn't change anything else to fix this?

Comment: @SnapADragon yes im sure, i created a blank Xamarin.Forms app with a splash activity just to test it at the time, just to make sure nothing in my code was causing this.

Comment: Just an Idea, disable the developer instrumentation only from release profile, so you won't lose the feature while debugging, and when you publish your application, then the app users will not face any problems

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the setting that @Isparia pointed out, so I tried running it in production mode. It appears that this issue does not happen in production mode, only in development. So I don't have to worry about this issue showing up for my users, even though I was seeing it in development.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the solution as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68343569/9210028

Basically, just set the application theme in the android project to the splash screen theme.

[image: Screenshot of Android Manifest opened in the the android project settings, with the application theme field highlighted]