# Xamarin Android - Splash screen flickering in Android 10

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I have updated a new Splash screen to my application. I tried all the suggestions given from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103310/splash-screen-is-resizing-when-switching-to-main-activity), but I still having splash screen flickering issues. I found this issues only occurred in Android 10, devices with Android 9.0 and below is working good.

I have racked my brain but I still have no idea what is the cause of issues. Would be grateful if someone can give me some advice. Thanks.

[image: flickering image]

Answer (score 2):

i believe i had this issue as well. do not use a separate splash activity. Set your `MainActivity` `Theme=@style/Theme.Splash`. Then in `MainActivity.OnCreate` change the theme manually

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the application theme field is set to the splash theme in project properties.
[image]

Comment: That was it for me, thanks!